# Class DAO don't get the Object

Tags: java, web, crud, dao

When i try to get an element by a few arguments in my Servlet, its values returns NULL. What can I do?

Class DAO:

```
public Premio getByDataLoteriaHorario(String date, int idLoteria, int idHorario) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, ParseException {
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    ResultSet rs;
    Premio premio = new Premio();
    String sqlString = "select * from Premio where dataPremio = ? AND idLoteria = ? AND idHorario = ?";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD");
    java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(date).getTime());

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    preparedStatement.setDate(1, data);
    preparedStatement.setInt(2, idLoteria);
    preparedStatement.setInt(3, idHorario);

    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        premio.setIdPremio(rs.getInt("idPremio"));
        premio.setIdLoteria(rs.getInt("idLoteria"));
        premio.setIdHorario(rs.getInt("idHorario"));
        premio.setIdGrupo(rs.getInt("idGrupo"));
        premio.setPremio(rs.getString("premio"));
        premio.setDataPremio(rs.getString("dataPremio"));   
    }
    preparedStatement.close();
    rs.close();

    return premio;
}
```

The MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Premio ( 
  idPremio INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  idLoteria INT, 
  idHorario INT, 
  idGrupo INT, 
  premio1 VARCHAR(4), 
  premio2 VARCHAR(4), 
  premio3 VARCHAR(4), 
  premio4 VARCHAR(4), 
  premio5 VARCHAR(4), 
  premioSoma VARCHAR(5), 
  premio7 VARCHAR(4), 
  dataPremio DATE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (idLoteria) REFERENCES Loteria(idLoteria), 
  FOREIGN KEY (idHorario) REFERENCES Horario(idHorario), 
  FOREIGN KEY (idGrupo) REFERENCES Bicho(idGrupo), 
  PRIMARY KEY (idPremio)
);
```

Comment: Fields inside premio are null? Maybe add source code for it.

Comment: when I select from MySQL Workbench it works. But from Servlet it returns me null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is when you call the database to award and dataPremio you send them in the rs.getString but I do not see them in your table I remain attentive to an answer

Answer (score 0):

I change all the Date types to String and it works! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is probably because timezone issues (Date has timezone, but also connection to MySQL has some timezone settings that I found confusing). I did similar - defined all dates as BIGINT to avoid any problems